# Why is class of one-dimensional vector spaces not axiomatizable?

Tags: vector-spaces, model-theory, vector-space-isomorphism

Prove, class of all one-dimensional vector spaces over R isn't axiomatizable in the signature    σ=< +, α, 0>, α* is single function vector multiplication by a scalar $\alpha$ of R.

There are thoughts about theorem of axiomatizability: let К is some class of model of some signature. Class $К$ is axiomatizable <=> it closed under isomorphism, elementary submodels and ultraproduct.

That is, we can construct isomorphism between models of one-dimensional and two-dimensional vector space over R, although two-dimensional vector space isn't in our class.

Comment: What happens when you take an ultrapower of a one-dimensional vector space (using a sufficiently large index set)?

Comment: Sorry, may be i don't undestand.. It will be in class K?

Comment: But what will be its cardinality?

Comment: Сontinuum, i think.

Comment: Sorry, i'm not right about isomorphism.

Comment: What ultrafelter should i take for ultapower?

Answer (score 4):

The class of one-dimensional vector spaces over the reals is not an elementary class in your language — it is the not the collection of models of any theory — because it does not respect the Löwenheim-Skolem theorem. The collection of models of any fixed theory with an infinite model contains models of arbitrarily large cardinality, but all one-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{R}$ have size continuum.

Comment: And becouse of there isn't enumerable model of one-dimensional vector spaces over the reals, it is enough. Yes?

And we needn't in proving fact, ultraproduct of one-dimensional vector spaces is not one-dimensional vector space.

Comment: No, because your language has size continuum. You have a separate unary function symbol for multiplying by $\alpha$, for every individual real number $\alpha$.